# Get physical drive size from command line

Tags: hard-drive, centos6

Is there a command that tells me whether I have 2.5 or 3.5" drives in a system?

Comment: The closest I can think of is to use `hdparm` to get drive model information and then look the model up online. Even then, this will only work with drives that aren't "hidden" behind a RAID controller.

Comment: Yeah, on with Dell.. even OMSA doesn't list the physical dimensions.  He looked up the info from the drive part number, confirmed the size for me.

Comment: It's worth mentioning that chassis size doesn't necessarily equate with platter size.  I know of 3.5" disks that contain 2.5" platters.

Comment: This is for ordering some replacement drives.   It seems I can get FIPS certified SEDs in some configurations, but not others (for my server model)